Integration where 3th party uses SF API when receiving ID in URL parameter - Sandbox CI/CD
We have currently this integration setup:
SF PROD - APPLICATION PROD
SF UAT - APPLICATION UAT
Both have their own clientid/clientsecret/securitytoken
Now we want to work more with seperate sandboxes > UAT > PROD.
This means that we spin up more sandboxes and want the APPLICATION to also connect to those. Obviously they won't spin up sandboxes with us. So I want to connect our sandboxes to the UAT of the Appplication.
Currently they move from Salesforce via www.application.com/SFID and the application updates the record found in the URL parameter (simplified explanation)
We use the oAuth2 username password flow. This means that every sandbox refresh triggers an security token reset and the Application admin needs to update those.
What strategy would be best here to setup the integration 'dynamically'?
I was thinking:

Switch to oauth2 client credentials flow (no user details, so no security token)
Add clientId parameter to the url 'www.application.com/ClientId/SFID
on Sandbox creation you can apparently set the Client Secret via tooling api, which we will set same as UAT and other sandboxes
Now the application knows the clientId, and clientSecret is always the same, use that to connect to the right ORG and update the right SF record.

What is best practise here? Creating an endpoint on the Application side which we update with new sandbox details it not feasible at the moment.
TLDR.
How do i create new sandboxes and keep incomming connected integration running when seending webhook calls from all sandboxes to 1 application instance?
